# How to send form in remote page using PHP, jQuery or Curl

Tags: php, jquery, curl

I have page name customer.php in this page, I have to call gift.php with query string. And gift.php page has a form set to auto submit.
I have try this using CURL but it gives 404 error. And using php file_get_contents this one also redirect to 404. And tried using jQuery Ajax, I haven't got any result, But Its working with iframe, but I belive it is not the best option

```
<iframe src="gift.php?name=John"></iframe>
```

Could someone please help me to do this using curl...

**this code not working**

```
$url =urlencode('gift.php?name=john');

$header = array("Accept: application/json");

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_ENCODING, "gzip");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'GET');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 'Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1; SV1; .NET CLR 1.0.3705; .NET CLR 1.1.4322)');

$retValue = curl_exec($ch);
$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch));
$ee       = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($ee);

print_r($retValue);
```

Comment: So where is the code?

Comment: @hindmost the code is not loading after save the question, when i go to edit mode, its visible

Comment: You have to set `CURLOPT_URL` option with absolute url. 'gift.php?name=john' is a relative url

Answer (score 1):

For curl don't use `$url =urlencode('gift.php?name=john');` and `$url` must contain domainname. For example `$url = 'http://domain.com/gift.php?name=' . urlencode('john');`